# How to deploy a JSP on to a server other than Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to deploy a JSP/servlet onto a server. Not tomcat but on a real web domain. This is my first time doing so and so far I exported it into a war file and placed the file onto the server. Nothing happened which is why I am here. All the google searches seem to concentrate on Tomcat which I have already ran the project on. Advice?

Comment: so how do you define a server?

Comment: tomcat is a servlet container... it's designed to host jsp's servlets, etc but without the heavy overhead of other JEE features that may not be required (JBoss, etc). You need some servlet/jsp container to run your WAR file... Apache doesn't understand anything except html and maybe PHP (with modules loaded). Jetty is another lightweight servlet container like tomcat.

Comment: Define a server? Well lets say I am using Godaddy or HostGator for example. I am having a issue connecting the dots on how to launch this JSP.

Comment: Neither of those support Java hosting from memory - many cheap hosting companies won't include Java support, so you need to make sure you find one that does.

Comment: What do you suggest? Also is my method of launching it onto the web correct?

Do you think those above mentioned would support spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's get really basic.  You want to see the compiled JSP in a browser, through some public URL, right?

First, find a place to host your application.  You can try Digital Ocean (starts at $5/mo), EATJ (free version available), Amazon AWS (free trial available), OpenShift (free gears available), your own computer with dynamic DNS, or many other options available through Google.

Next, you packed your compiled code to a war file.  That war file needs to be unpacked (deployed) using some software.

There are numerous ways to handle this (Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, etc.).  They all have their pros and cons.  Pick one and learn the very basics.  Tomcat doesn't require a separate web server but you can set one up with it if you like.  At this stage, I would keep it simple and not do that yet.

Lastly, set up GoDaddy (or whomever you used to get your URL) to point to the IP address of that server.  If your server is running and enough time has passed for the changes to propagate, you should see your page.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty other J2EE server for example, JBoss and Glassfish. Each one has it's own way to deploy your war files. For example, Glassfish is throught a web administration console (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html) and in JBoss you need to deploy the war file in a specific directory (http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/deployer-howto.html).
It depends on which J2EE server you are using.

Now if you want to get your own server and configure it:

1. Get the server or VPS
2. Install JAVA
3. Install Apache
4. Install a J2EE server (I prefer glassfish)
5. Configure glassfish with apache (http://www.codefactorycr.com/glassfish-behind-apache.html) to use apache in front of glassfish
6. You may want to block the ports 4848 and 8080 used by glassfish
7. Deploy your webapp
8. Have fun!!!

PS: I'm assuming you have root access to the server

Comment: And if you need a VPS I use DigitalOcean, they are very nice, good support, low price and root access

Answer (score 0):

Easy Apache Tomcat 7 install after,

Run Code via SSH:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/addservlets2 --domain=domain.com
```

For Linux.